# Who can we call a musafir (Traveller)?

Tags: terminology, travelling

There are cases where the `Rasul (the Messenger) p.b.u.h` did not spell out specific criteria for a certain condition/situation.

For example the minimum distance traveled to qualify as a musafir (passenger). In this instant,for example would the criteria to be a traveler depends what the uruf of the society regards the condition of a traveler.

Or would it depends on the individual judgment and situation i.e. if he travels in a comfortable car, the distance to qualify as a musafir would be much further than if he travels by foot.

Comment: Similar answer for a different question @ http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25034/12537

Answer (score 1):

A musafir (traveler) is one who leaves the city limits of his/her hometown intending a journey of 48 miles or greater. This is the opinion of the vast majority of Islamic scholars and has been deduced from several verses, hadiths, and scenarios from the life of the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) and his companions.

Answer (score -1):

Briefly speaking, generally, in Islamic Fiqh, Musafer or passenger is considered as a person who has moved (got far) at least 8 Farsakh (unit of length equal to (about) 5.5km) from his homeland (the place(town or…) of his life) by noticing to its specific conditions. Or keeps out 4 Farsakhs from his/her homeland and return 4 Farsakh to his homeland. Without staying 10 other days. Consequently such a person is counted as passenger and has his/her specific Ahkams.

Let’s see some specific issues regarding the passenger, such as:

- A person who take trip for a haram practice, is not considered as
  Musafir.
- A person whose job is travelling, is not considered as Musafir
  (except his first trip).
- A person who intends to stay in a city at least 10 days or more, then
  he doesn’t considered as Musafir case..
- And some other issues. For more complete info. You’d better refer to
  the references.

  ---

**Reference:**

- [www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/63872)
- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Article/View/84379/?ParentID=70841)

Comment: -1. Either add English references or include proof within your post. This is an English site. Will update once you do.

Comment: Google translate gives you the option to translate paragraphs therefore you can use that to assist you in providing evidence that are more beneficial to others! I would not recommend them using it as they will not tell whether the translation is correct! Jazzak Allah Kheir