# Do I have to fast if I will be staying at a travel destination for 15 days or more?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, hanafi, travelling, fatwa-explanation

I will be traveling to India with my mother for her treatment during this Ramadan. From What I have [read](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/darululoomtt/52212), one is no more considered a traveler if he stays in the destination city for 15 days or more.

Now I don't know the exact days I will have to stay there but the doctor has told us that my mother's medical procedure will be completed in 15 days. Will I be considered a resident in the assumption from the doctor?

Being a central Asian I am a little concerned on how I will manage to take care of everything as I am not used to the hot climate in India especially fasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last Hajj, the prophet PBUH he traveled to Mecca on a Sunday, resided there for Sunday until Thursday and left on Thursday. He cut short his prayers during that entire stay.

> أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: " قدم مكة في حجة الوداع يوم الأحد، الرابع من ذي الحجة وأقام فيها الأحد والاثنين والثلاثاء والأربعاء وخرج يوم الخميس إلى منى، فأقام -صلى الله عليه وسلم- في مكة أربعة أيام يقصر الصلاة. الحديث متفق عليه

Imam Ahmed and Abu Dadood reported that the prophet stayed in Tabook 20 days as a traveler.

> أن النبي -صلى الله عليه وسلم- أقام مدداً مختلفة يقصر فيها، فأقام في تبوك عشرين يوماً يقصر الصلاة، أخرجه الإمام أحمد وأبو داود.

Imam Malik and Alshafai say the residence limit is 4 days, once you stay longer the rules of a traveler does not apply to you anymore.

The Hanafi on the other hand, raised the limit to 15 days.

Imam Ibn Tamima, went to the extent to say that the rules apply to you as long as you there are long as you do not become a resident.

Source of the Fatwa: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/5891

Personally, I think that if you are staying in a place and do not know the length of your stay you can take the rules of a traveler. However, if you are going and know you will stay 9 months for example for studying, then you shouldn't.

Comment: The doctor said it will be at least 18 days, so I decided to fast. Although I have become slow and not as active but it is not as hard as i thought it would be. May Allah continue to give me the strength to keep on fasting.